# No option to set Content = Static Cells in UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

So this is probably a trivial issue, but I keep encountering Xcode screenshots of the attribute inspector of a TableView that has a content attribute where you can specify Static content. However, on my end that attribute is nowhere to be found.

[image: Notice the marked attribute]

[image: Notice how that attribute is not present.]

Anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 5):

Table view content (Dynamic prototypes/static cells) setting seems only available in Interface Builder if you are using Storyboard. I can't see them either when I am working with table views in a xib file.

Comment: That sucks... And makes no sense, but you're absolutely right. It works fine in the StoryBoard. Wonder if this classifies as a bug?

Comment: Can confirm it's still the case.